# Refresh GridView inside Update Panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I have a gridview contained inside an update panel. I edit a record in the gridview using a button which is inside the gridvied and it does update panel postback( __doPostBack), then I update my dataset for the gridview and try to refresh the griview with new data source but I am getting the following error.

I rebind my gridview as follows,

```
gvwSearchResult.DataSource = dsP1.prSearchItem;
gvwSearchResult.DataBind();
UpdatePanel1.Update();

Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:   
 Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:
 Invalid postback or callback argument.  
 Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or 
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
 For security purposes, 
this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  
If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or 
callback data for validation.
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._endPostBackScriptResource.axd:307
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._parseDeltaScriptResource.axd:749
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmitCompletedScriptResource.axd:584
(anonymous function)ScriptResource.axd:22
(anonymous function)ScriptResource.axd:1519
Sys.Net.WebRequest.completedScriptResource.axd:2924
_onReadyStateChange
```

Any Idea?

Comment: The edit button is it autogenerated or is it in a template?

Answer (score 1):

Are you binding your gridview inside pageLoad? If yes then please check for

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
 {
     //Bind your gridview.
 }
```

Your control might be regenerating before the databind. That can happen if you are binding the control before the delete operation. Check your code under pageLoad & also under the button event. Only data bind in the end & not in between.

Comment: I am binding it inside my update panel load,
protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {}

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused because of the EventValidation failure. The below thread shows how to debug such exceptions.

[Conditional update panel](http://couldbedone.blogspot.in/2007/09/conditional-updatepanel-and-event.html)

Comment: Yes.. I do update the updatepanel and my grid is inside the the update panel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your button has UseSubmitBehaviour property set to false. It should be rendered as input type = "button" not "submit". Don't know why but for me this change worked..

Answer (score 0):

I set EnableEventValidation="false" then it worked. But not sure of the correct way of doing it